# Math to set tangential force?

Tags: physics, mathematics, javascript

I have an 2-dimensional planet at coordinate (pX, pY) and an object at the surface of the planet at some coordinates (oX, oY). I want to have the object go left or right when the user press the keys, which I'd like to simulate by applying a force. I have a homemade physics engine built and all I'm missing is the x/y amounts to use to apply the force in a tangential direction.

What calculation is needed to apply a tangential force clockwise/counterclockwise on an object at (oX, oY) around a center of (pX, pY)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a unit vector tangent to the planet surface:

```
v = normalize((pY - oY, oX - pX))
```

Then just multiply `v` by your force amount.

Comment: How does the normalize function work?

Comment: @AaronFranke Maybe [this link](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-natural-simulations/programming-vectors/a/vector-magnitude-normalization) can explain properly.

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate the relative coordinates using `rX = oX - pX` and `rY = oY - pY`

Next, we'll find the angle. Use the [Atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) method: `angle = atan2(rY, rX)`

Next, more trigonometry! We should be able to do `totalforce * sin(angle)` to find the amount of force to be applied on the X-axis and `totalforce * -cos(angle)` to find the amount of force to be applied on the Y-axis. Change totalforce to be positive or negative based on the direction desired.

Comment: While your answer gives the correct result, calling `sin` or `cos` after `atan2` is an indication that there is a much simpler operation available, avoiding trigonometry altogether.